# How to get Azure Gallery or Marketplace items with Azure SDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, dnx

I have been working with Azure SDK in an ASP .NET core website and I need to get the list of items available from the galleries or from the marketplace in the new portal.

I thought the package "Microsoft.Azure.Gallery": "2.6.2-preview", may be useful, but I'm getting an error when trying to get the list of items.
Error is 
Hyak.Common.CloudException: Missing api version query string. Allowed values are [2014-09-01,2015-04-01,2015-10-01]

And I can't find a way to change it since the ApiVersion property is read-only.

Having said that, how could I get the list of gallery or marketplace items using Azure SDK.